# Restriction of reflexive sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety and let $\mathcal{L}$ be a rank 1 reflexive sheaf on $X$. Let $Y$ be a closed normal projective subvariety in $X$ such that the singularities of $X$ intersect $Y$ in codimension at least 2. Is it true that $\mathcal{L}\mid_Y$ is reflexive?

The example I have in mind is when $X$ weighted projective space (well-formed) and $Y$ is a well-formed weighted complete intersection in $X$.

Comment: Am I missing something, or what is wrong with restricting the isomorphism $L\to L^{\vee\vee}$ to $Y$?

Comment: @red_trumpet restriction does not commute with taking duals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. The restriction $\mathcal{L}|_{Y}$ might not even be torsion-free. Let me give a simple affine example (one can get a projective example easily by compactifying by gluing a smooth chart at "infinity").

**Some motivating setup.** Perhaps to make the computations seem less cryptic, let me comment on a way to produce examples of reflexive rank 1 sheaves and compute restrictions. Let us work over an algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic $0$ for simplicity. We may start with a smooth quasiprojective variety $Z$ equipped with an action of a finite group $G$. We have a quotient stack $Z/G$ and there is a coarse space morphism $\pi: Z/G \to Z//G$, where $X:= Z//G$ is a normal variety. Given any line bundle $\mathcal{M}$ on $Z/G$ (i.e. an equivariant line bundle on $Z$), the pushforward $\pi_*\mathcal{M}$ is a rank 1 reflexive sheaf on $X$. If the stabilizers of points of $Z$ act nontrivially on the fibers of $\mathcal{M}$, it may very well be that $\pi_*(\mathcal{M})$ is not a line bundle. Furthermore, it is often easy to compute restrictions of $\pi_*(\mathcal{M})$. Namely, for any $Y \to X$ there is a base-change formula $\pi_*(\mathcal{M})|_{Y} = (\pi_Y)_*\mathcal{M}|_{(Z\times_X Z)/G}$ where $\pi_Y: (Z\times_X Y)/G \to Y$ the base-change coarse space morphism.

**Example.** Ok, let us apply this in the simplest example that could lead something interesting. We take $Z = \mathbb{A}^3 = Spec(R)$ where $R= k[x,y,z]$. We let the group $G=\mu_2$ act on $\mathbb{A}^3$ with weight $1$ on each of the variables $x,y,z$. The quotient is $X = Spec(R^{G})$, where $R^{G} = k[x^2, y^2,z^2, xy,xz,yz] \subset k[x,y,z]$ is the subring of invariants. We may consider the canonical bundle $\mathcal{M} = \omega_Z = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^3}\langle1\rangle$ of  $Z$, which is the structure sheaf $R$ of $Z$ with equivariant structure twisted by the nontrivial character of $\mu_2$. We set $\mathcal{L} := \pi_*(\mathcal{M})$ under the coarse space morphism $\pi: Z/G \to X$, which is nothing but the $R^G$-module of invariants $(R\langle1\rangle)^G$.

We denote by $Y \subset X$ the vanishing locus of $(x^2,xy,xz)$. This is isomorphic to $Spec(R_Y)$ where $R_Y = k[y^2,yz,y^2] \subset k[z,y]$, so it is the normal surface obtained by quotienting $k[y,z]$ by $\mu_2$. By the base-change formula (or more concretely exactness of taking $G$-invariants), the restriction $\mathcal{M}|_{Y} = (R\langle 1\rangle)^G \otimes_{R^G} R_Y$ is equal to the $R_Y$ module of invariants $(R\langle 1\rangle \otimes_{R^G} R_Y)^G$. Notice that the fiber product is $R \otimes _{R^G} R_Y = k[x,y,z]/(x^2,xy,xz)$. In particular, we have $kx \subset k[x,y,z]/(x^2,xy,xz) = R \otimes _{R^G} R_Y$ as a torsion submodule of length one. Therefore, $R\langle 1 \rangle \otimes_{R^G} R_Y = (k[x,y,z]/(x^2,xy,xz))\langle 1\rangle$ has $kx\langle 1\rangle$ as a $G$-invariant submodule. When we take invariants, this survives to yield a corresponding torsion submodule inside $\mathcal{L}|_{Y}$.

**Some remarks** Of course you can just phrase this in terms of equations without the "taking invariants" bit, and you can check directly that $\mathcal{L} \otimes \mathcal{O}_Y$ has torsion.

I think that one can get examples where the restriction is torsion-free but not $S_2$ by playing around with similar constructions.

The torsion (or the failure of $S_2$ in other examples) is coming from higher Tors of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ with the local cohomology of $\mathcal{L}$ at the singular locus. In nice circumstances, it is possible to use duality (say by embedding $X$ into a smooth variety) to give some "explicit" conditions on $Y$ an $\mathcal{L}$ that guarantee that $\mathcal{L}|_{Y}$ is reflexive. For example, see the Section 1.1 of the book "Moduli of sheaves" by Huybrechts and Lehn for a possible example of such conditions.